# Is anyone using ORAM in practice?

Tags: oblivious-ram

Oblivious RAM has been around in theory for about 30 years at this point.

Is anyone using it in practice? Has it made its way into industry? (Including any variants such as MPC ORAM or ORAM that uses trusted hardware for the client.)

Comment: I would love to know as well.  I would hazard to guess, no, due to the time it takes and the overhead involved as you have to transverse that "tree" structure.  It has never come up on the "hardware side" of things.  I've heard about the desire to use it cloud applications for an extra layer of security; however, I know of no one who has actually used it due to the need for a dedicated compiler (this could just be due to my poor understanding)

Comment: interesting question. are there any good technical resources on ORAM you can suggest @bdegnan?

Comment: I could totally see the Signal contact discovery server code run inside SGX using ORAM (but I'm not sure whether they actually do).

Comment: @kodlu I do not.  I only know about this from a presentation when I asked why not just use a customized MMU.  It turned into a huge conversation later where I talked about what we do on the hardware side.   I can say that there was funding for using it to secure memory for the JEDI program.

Comment: There have been some explicit ORAM tools built. I've heard of [ObliviC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1153.pdf) before, and in googling found [Oblivi Store](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~elaine/docs/ObliviStore.pdf) as well. That being said, I've also read ORAM papers which are explicitly in the "theoretical gains at the cost of practice" camp. One way to tell is to check what notion of sorting they use --- the AKS sorting network is $O(n\log n)$ time, and Batcher odd-even merge sort is $O(n(\log n)^2)$. AKS is slower until arrays get of size $\approx 2^{80}$ though. Some ORAM papers use AKS anyway.